# Showing Language in Power Automate when using Multilingual Form

Tags: multilingual, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I have a multilingual Microsoft Form. I want to show a column for Language in my Power Automate flow, but I cannot find a way.
When I export the data from my form manually, the export shows Language.
But, within Power Automate, I do not seem to have the option to include this.

It's a key part of my data, so any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

See below the Microsoft Form, its just a set of questions, but the user has the ability to change the language in the corner, because its a multilingual form.

[image: Microsoft Form]

When I set up my Power Automate flow, the only options to include are the actual questions from the form...there is no way to add language.

[image: Power Automate]

But I know Microsoft is storing that information because if I export the data without Power Automate, Language is automatically included.

Comment: Can you show us the output and what you want it to be? Makes it easier to help.

Comment: Let me know if the above screenshots help! I essentially just want there to be the option to show Language in Power Automate but its not there, as you can see in the screenshot above.

Comment: Doesn’t look like it. My suggestion would be to use the language detection API (cognitive service) in Azure to interrogate a text field to work out what language they’ve replied in. Alternatively, have a field directly on the form that allows them to select their language so it’s captured. I prefer the former option though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Forms formular which is synchronizing with an Excel sheet.
For this, go to your One Drive and create a new forms formular:

[image: Create new formular]

After adding the option to change the language in the forms, you have to synchronize your responses in Excel again:

[image: Synchronize again with excel]

Now, you get a new Excel file with answers and the column "language" from the forms.

You can access to this Excel in Power Automate to use the column language in the flow. For this, use the action "Get a row". The key value is the `ResponseID` of your forms response.